# Laravel make:auth problems, can't view the premade login or register page

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I've created a laravel 5.2 project. I added a database, and some basic views and controllers (Note: I think this is my problem). I then ran the artisan make:auth command. It ran successfully. Despite me already having a login and home view and controller.

I can view laravel's premade 'home' page on my localhost. But once I click the login or register link, things break and I get,

"No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid."

I've de-bugged this and insured my keys are correct and in the appropriate places.

This is my routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

I obviously have no route here for login or register, but shouldn't make:auth create routing behind the scenes? From what I've read, this should have worked out of the box. What am I missing here? Any help would be great,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved my problem.

I had originally set the key in my .env file to

`APP_KEY=854uQ9...(random 32 bit key)`

I had also set config/app.php to

```
'key' => env('854uQ9...(same 32 bit key as above)')
```

**NOTE the missing ''APP_KEY''**. Once I changed config/app.php back to

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'SomeRandomString'),
```

the links worked. I can now change 'SomeRandomString' to my app key, but as the .env file is checked first, I assume this can be left as is.

Thanks for the replys.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
$ php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried this and it doesn't fix my problem. I'm not sure what it's supposed to do to be honest. In my app.php I have 'key' => env('old_key_here') and now in .env I have APP_KEY=new_key with my old key appended on the end. Am I missing something else here?

Comment: key:generate generates a new key and save it in your .env file

Comment: if you don't want to use the `.env` delete it and laravel falls back to all the stuff in the `config`-folder. Check you `config/app.php` for a key afterwards